# Trigger keypress event with event listener WITHOUT jquery

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keypress

I want to trigger a keypress event as a reaction to an event listener without using jQuery

```js
let arrow = document.querySelector("#arrow");
//When you click on the arrow
arrow.addEventListener('click', function(e){
// It triggers a keypress (down)
   $(document).trigger(keypressing);
  });
```

[EDIT] I tried this out, but doesn't seem to trigger the simulated keypress :

```js
let arrow = document.querySelector(".scroll-down");


arrow.addEventListener('click', function(e){
console.log('simulating the keypress of down arrow')
document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {'key': 'x'}));
});


$(window).bind('keypress', function(event) {
 if (event.key == 'x') { 
 console.log('its working with x')
}
});
```

Comment: Use [.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

Comment: What is your `#arrow` element ? input ? button ?

Comment: It is a div container that wraps 3 spans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dispatchEvent` to trigger event.
Example: trigger `keypress` with key `x`

```js
document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {'key': 'x'}));
```

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

---

This worked for me to trigger key down event:

```
// Create listener 
document.addEventListener('keydown', () => { console.log('test')})

// Create event
const keyboardEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
const initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? 'initKeyboardEvent' : 'initKeyEvent';

keyboardEvent[initMethod](
  'keydown', // event type: keydown, keyup, keypress
  true,      // bubbles
  true,      // cancelable
  window,    // view: should be window
  false,     // ctrlKey
  false,     // altKey
  false,     // shiftKey
  false,     // metaKey
  40,        // keyCode: unsigned long - the virtual key code, else 0
  0          // charCode: unsigned long - the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
);

// Fire event
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
```

Comment: arrow.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   console.log('simulating the keypress of down arrow')
   document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {'keyCode': '40'}));
});                                                                                                                                                                In order to press the down arrow key ?